# Spring boot endpoint is not authenticated

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am trying to learn `oauth2` along with `jwt` so my reference link is

https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-oauth2-jwt-example

I am using `spring boot 1.5.15`

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    static final String CLIEN_ID = "devglan-client";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "devglan-secret";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1*60;
    static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 6*60*60;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("as466gf");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

        configurer
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIEN_ID)
                .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT )
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).
                refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }
}
```

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users").access("hasRole('SCT_USER')")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}


    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Autowired
        private SecurityHandler securityHandler;

        @Autowired
        private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;


        private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/",
                "**/",
                "/newUser",
                "/forgetPassword",
                "/login",
                "**/uploads/**",
                "/assets/**",
                "/api/updateCardStatus",
                "/fonts/**",
                "/users"
        };

       /* @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .authorizeRequests()

                    *//*    antMatchers("/**").*//*
                    .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).
                    permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin").hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN").and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .successHandler(securityHandler)
                    .and()
                    .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .rememberMe();
        }*/

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .anonymous().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll();
        }



        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws  Exception{
            web.ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/api/updateCardStatus","*/uploads/***","/api/getUsersDetail","/api/getStudentDetails","/api/getAccountLoad","/api/issueDirectives","/api/changePassword","/api/cardActivation","/api/CustomerAccountCardDetails","/api/accountLoad","/api/updateConsumersProfile","/api/verifyCvv"
                            ,"/api/updatePrepaidCardStatus","/api/getStatementData");
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }


        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(SecurityUtils.passwordEncoder());
        }


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

now with these configuration when I call

http://localhost:8080/oauth/token

this gives me access and refresh which is what I want. but now

I have a controller which looks like

```
 @GetMapping("/users")
    public Map<String,String> getUsers(){
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name","sagar");
        map.put("job","developers");
        return map;
    }
```

so I am calling this endpoint like this

[http://localhost:8080/users](http://%20http://localhost:8080/users)

now what I expect is that whenever I call this endpoint this call should be authenticated. but it simply returns me

```
{
    "name": "sagar",
    "job": "developers"
}
```

even when I don't send any tokens. I expect this endpoint to be allowed to the use having role `SCT_USER`.

Why this is not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see carefully on my version of SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

/*@Autowired
private SecurityHandler securityHandler;

@Autowired
private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;
*/

private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
        "/css/**",
        "/js/**",
        "/images/**",
        "/",
        "**/",
        "/newUser",
        "/forgetPassword",
        "/login",
        "**/uploads/**",
        "/assets/**",
        "/api/updateCardStatus",
        "/fonts/**",
        "/users"
};

   /* @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()

                *//*    antMatchers("/**").*//*
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).
                permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN").and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error")
                .successHandler(securityHandler)
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
                .and()
                .rememberMe();
    }*/

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
}



@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws  Exception{
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/api/updateCardStatus","*/uploads/***","/api/getUsersDetail","/api/getStudentDetails","/api/getAccountLoad","/api/issueDirectives","/api/changePassword","/api/cardActivation","/api/CustomerAccountCardDetails","/api/accountLoad","/api/updateConsumersProfile","/api/verifyCvv"
                    ,"/api/updatePrepaidCardStatus","/api/getStatementData");
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Autowired
public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password("pass")
            .roles("ADMIN", "USER").and()
            .withUser("appuser")
            .password("pass123").roles("USER");
}

/*@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(SecurityUtils.passwordEncoder());
}*/


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder(){
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
    TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
    handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
    handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
    handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    return handler;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
    TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
    store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
    return store;
}


}
```

Two important point here

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
```

And

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api-        docs/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

And don't forget to fix your typo in ResourceServerConfig where you have `access("hasRole('SCT_USER')")`

instead of

```
access("hasRole('USER')")
```

I've created test example for exactly your code. 
https://github.com/alex-petrov81/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/spring-boot-endpoint-not-auth

Comment: it is not the case i have already provided the code of Securityconfig class

Comment: After examining your code carefully, I found one bug: hasRole('SCT_USER'), but in your credentials you are using USER role. I will change my answer shortly

Comment: this fixed it. a lot of thanks. it took me hours and i was still unable to detect them. what does this @Order annotation do ?

Comment: After release 1.5.x OAuth2 resource server order is set to SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER - 1 which has now definitely lower priority then basic WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter order. So it leads to specify @Order annotation to restore WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter order. It enable OAuth filter in Spring filter chain.

Comment: it appears that this order thing mess up my other urls. like if i call localhost:8080/admin it opened admin.html page previously. but after keeping order annotation it now returns some xml error. 

how can i say for e.g http://localhost:8080/api/** (treat it as api) and remaining urls are normal redirection url

Comment: I saw that you already have PUBLIC_MATCHERS in your code. All you need to do is @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws  Exception{
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS);
    }